# Searching for Item in CSV

Tags: python, excel, csv

I'm trying to search through a .csv file (that I open in Excel) and find a specific number in a field. The number I'm searching for comes from a user input in a GUI. If the number is found in the field, then all items on the same row, in other fields, will be outputted. This is what the file has in it:
[screen shot of the file in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOKum.png)
The problem is that I can't seem to create a piece of code that can read through the .csv and find the number.
This is what I have so far (this is only the part of the code that doesn't work):

```
def search(): # defining the function
term=str(e3.get()) # getting the user input and setting it to the varible 'term'
import csv # from all my researching, this is required to open the file
open('Book1.csv') # opens the file
# the code to look through the file would be here. It must search for the number in the correct field and output an error if it can't find it
print() #this will print the data in the same row as the number from the different fields for the user
```

If you have a solution, please give me the code that will do exactly what I need it to do. I would appreciate if you explained what it did but it doesn't matter if you don't. Thanks for replying in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. So you want an answer but don't care if it isn't explained? Don't you have an interest to learn the functions to use them yourself later?

Comment: _"Give me the code that will do exactly what I need it to"_ ...Stack Overflow isn't really a "free code writing service", more of a learning place.  Might want to check out the [tour].

Comment: Sorry to the two people who said I used the website incorrectly but I was desperate for an answer when I had been coding for nearly 12 hours straight with no luck. I will keep your advice in mind for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this using python's `csv` module:

```
import csv

def search():
    term = #something
    reader = csv.reader(open('Book1.csv', 'r'))
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == term:
            return row[1:]
    return None # return None if no match
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! I'm going to need to edit it a bit for it to work correctly with the rest of the program but otherwise I couldn't ask for more. Thanks a lot. Also if you could tell me what each individual line does so I can use this in the future I would appreciate it but don't fell as if you have to.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the pandas solution:

Let's start with creating sample data:

```
import io
s = u"""bar_code,item,price
1,Spam,0.1
2,Beans,0.2
3,Egg,0.2
4,Milk,0.3"""

file = io.StringIO(s)
```

And now the actual code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(file) 
#df = pd.read_csv('Book1.csv')

lookup = 0.2 # lookup value
matches = df[df['price'] == lookup] # filter rows

# if you find items
if len(matches)>0:
    items = matches.drop('price', axis=1).values.tolist() #drop price column
    print(items)
else:
    print("No match!")
```

Returns:

```
[[2, 'Beans'], [3, 'Egg']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I would recommend this answer to anyone who is having a similar problem but not the same one.